# Passing a method signature using delegates to a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

In order to represent the method that executes on a thread I am using 
`ParameterizedThreadStart` and passing the name of the method.  In this case the method name is `SelectJob` and the instantiation is as follows:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart starter = new ParameterizedThreadStart(SelectJob);

protected void SelectJob(object index)
{
     ...
}
```

In order to reuse a portion of code I would like, if possible, to store the method name in a variable but the IntelliSense shows the method signature for `ParameterizedThreadStart` as `ParameterizedThreadStart(void (object) target)` and I'm not sure how I could store this sort of value.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) I realize this is a delegate so after reading [How to: Declare, Instantiate, and Use a Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I tried to declare ...

```
delegate void Del(string str);
Del selectDelegate = SelectJob;
```

... but since the `SelectJob` method is not static I am not able to do this.  Simply making the method static is not an easy option.

Is there another way of making this declaration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise the delegate instance inside a constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ParameterizedThreadStart starter;

    public MyClass()
    {
        starter = SelectJob;

        Del selectDelegate = SelectJob;
    }

    delegate void Del(string str);

    protected void SelectJob(object index)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I rarely look into the use of delegates and, while not conceptually difficult, I often struggle to instantiate them correctly.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign it to an Action field in your constructor:

```
   class Boo
    {
        public Boo()
        {
            _myDelegate = SelectJob;

        }

        Action<object> _myDelegate ;
        protected void SelectJob(object index)
        {

        }
    }
```

Alternatively, have a method that always returns your delegate:

```
   class Hoo
    {


        protected Action<object> SelectJobDelegate(object index)
        {
            return o =>
                       {

                           // do something with o
                       };
        }
    }
```